Routing traffic to a WSL2 VM. What am I missing?
HOST_IP = 192.168.0.132/24
VM_IP = 172.30.110.54/20
(different subnets)
The HOST computer is able to reach the WSL2 VM, but I don't understand the process that makes that possible.
I was assuming that the HOST can route traffic to the VM because of this entry in the
HOST's routing table:
Destination       Netmask            Gateway        Interface 
172.30.96.0    255.255.240.0         On-link       172.30.96.1
So I was expecting that if I add a routing entry to my ROUTER like this-- :
Destination       Netmask               Gateway        Interface
172.30.96.0    255.255.240.0         192.168.0.132        LAN   
--that when trying to reach the VM from another computer on the network, the request would be routed to 192.168.0.132 (the HOST computer) and subsequently be routed to the WSL2 VM.
But I cannot reach the VM this way.
(I know I can do portproxy on the HOST, but I wish to know why the routing method isn't working.)
